# access Context.ConnectionID outside of hub in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to be able to send message to specific user account with SignalR.
Right now I can send to everyone!
I am looking for any way to have access to context.ConnectionID in controller outside of hub. I tried accessing it inside of controller with iHubContext and inside of hub I tried to save value of connectionID in session but both are not supported.

What would be best way to access connectionID from Controller outside of Hub?

here is action method from ChatController that is used for sending message to everyone

```
public IActionResult PosaljiPoruku()
    {
        _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("PrimljenaPoruka", "aaa");
        return PartialView("SubmitFormPartial");
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Hi @sasko, any updates about this case?

Comment: Didnt figure out how to map user and connectionID together unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

> What would be best way to access connectionID from Controller outside of Hub?

From [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0) about sending messages from outside a hub, you would find:

*When hub methods are called from outside of the `Hub` class, there's no caller associated with the invocation. Therefore, there's no access to the `ConnectionId`, `Caller`, and `Others` properties.*

> I want to be able to send message to specific user account with SignalR.

You can mapping user and `ConnectionId(s)` while client connected to Hub server, then if you want to send message to specific user from controller action outside of your Hub, you can query mapping table to get corresponding connection Id(s) first based on user name etc, and passing connection Id(s) to action method.

```
await _hubContext.Clients.Client("connection_id_here").SendAsync("PrimljenaPoruka", "aaa");
```

Besides, you can achieve same by creating single-user group (a group for each user), and then send a message to that group when you want to reach only that specific user.

```
await _hubContext.Clients.Group("group_name_here").SendAsync("PrimljenaPoruka", "aaa");
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for respodning. Sorry for my late response! I want to map somehow connectionID to user. But i cant find examples of how to do it outside of documentation. AFAIK since i use ihubcontext for connection i cant call any custom methods from hub in controller.